# Address already in use exception. Port number not released/freed even after closing the server

Tags: java, linux, port, pid

I have a client server application. By default incomingClientApplicationPort as 6001. My server is installed in linux environment. I close the server by running the shell script. While closing the server following command runs.

```
kill_server()
{
  pid=`server_pid`
  if [ "$pid" != "" ] ; then
    /bin/kill -9 $pid
    echo Server stopped.
  else
    echo Server is not running.
  fi
}
```

So basically I am using kill -9 $pid

The problem is even after closing the server, when I try to start the server again I get an exception "Address already in use" that is port 6001 is not released. Although this thing doesn't replicate everytime but how can it be fixed ?

Comment: trying a more graceful shutdown? i.e. just kill without the -9 parameter.

Comment: Beyond that, this might also depend on what exactly your Java code does. You should try to come up with a real [mcve] here.

Comment: Jared --- seriously? He asks "why is the port still in use"; and you close as dup to "port still in use; use another one"?

Comment: Does it keep the port open permanently after the kill?  IIRC I had a similar problem, and the OS took a minute or so to finally close the port after the process had finished.